Email and Text Reminders - X hours before or day before at specific time?
We have a system where people commit to attending certain events and we need to send out reminders. The events can be any time of the day, from 8am to 10pm. The purpose of the reminders is to make sure they remember their commitments and they won't forget.
From a UX perspective, is it better to send reminders X hours before the event or the day before at a specific time?
The problem with X hours before the event is that if we send reminders 12 hours before the events, then the ones in the morning are sent the day before but the evening events are sent in the morning.
We are leaning towards a consolidated "digest" reminder with a list of all their commitments the day before and another one the morning of. Thoughts?

The day before and then again on the morning-of seems to be redundant. Better would be the day before and then maybe 15 minutes before start.
But honestly, these could only be suggestions for defaults!
You need to give the user control over how shi wants to handle reminders. Some may have their own system in place and do not need any. Some do not like the notification sound or vibro pattern and want to adjust it. etc.
